# Xcode: link actions from View to Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have created a `.xib`-file to contain my modal view that's being presented on multiple pages. This view is being instantiated by the `FavoritesViewController`, which in turn is being instantiated when pressing a button on the different pages.

I'd like to create an action for the button and link it to the FavoritesViewController. The .xib-file in this case is only a View, not a View Controller, which is in my understanding the reason that this cannot be done.

I've tried linking the button to an action I've already created, but it doesn't want to establish a connection to the code.

How can this be achieved?

[image: Is this possible?]

Comment: You can only create action on View where it is controlled by associated view controller. If you want to perform action on across view controllers you need to use delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it now by using delegates, as suggested by BenjG37 and bpolat. Thanks!

My `FavoritesView.xib` is linked to `FavoritesView.swift`. This contains the code of the view and defines the protocol for the delegate. I've linked a *dismiss*-button's action to the view and call the delegated `exitFromBlur` method.

```
// FavoritesView.swift
protocol FavoritesViewDelegate {
  func exitFromBlur()
}

class FavoritesView: UIView {
  var delegate: FavoritesViewDelegate?

  @IBAction func exitBlur(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.exitFromBlur()
  }
}
```

This is the view controller, which gets instantiated by any of the other views of my storyboard when clicking a button. I now implement the protocol and its method `exitFromBlur`. It also tells the view it's now its delegate.

```
// FavoritesViewController.swift
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController, FavoritesViewDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let subView = UINib(nibName: "FavoritesView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as FavoritesView
    subView.delegate = self
  }

  func exitFromBlur() {
    println("It works!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action must be set in the FavoriteView.swift file instead of the ViewController file !

Comment: I would need to access methods/attributes that are set in the `FavoritesViewController` in the IBAction. If that's placed in the `FavoritesView.swift` instead, how would I go about that?

Comment: You can use this  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm   tutorial !